Is there a way to make a wait or delay in a function in AnyLogic?
I am trying to simulate a smart traffic light system that prioritizes lanes based on vehicle density at an intersection. My goal is to control the traffic light phases by first checking the density of each lane, sorting the lanes by density, and checking if there are significant differences. If there is a significant difference, the system should cycle through the lanes based on the density. If not, it should default to a regular cycle (north, south, west, east).
However, I am facing a problem with controlling the timing and delays between switching traffic lights. Within the function, the traffic lights phase all at once because I can't control the timing or introduce delays effectively.
Setup of the simulation in AnyLogic
This is what the function I had in mind:
int NorthRoadDensity = 10;
int SouthRoadDensity = 10;
int WestRoadDensity = 10;
int EastRoadDensity = 10;

int[] desities = {NorthRoadDensity, SouthRoadDensity, WestRoadDensity, EastRoadDensity};
int[] laneOrder = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int densityThreshold = 5;

void trafficLightControl()
{
  // Lane Sorting:
  for (int i = 0; i < densities.length - 1; i++) 
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < densities.length - i - 1; j++) 
      {
        if (densities[j] < densities[j + 1]) 
        {
          // Swap densities
          int tempDensity = densities[j];
          densities[j] = densities[j + 1];
          densities[j + 1] = tempDensity;
  
          // Swap corresponding lanes
          int tempLane = laneOrder[j];
          laneOrder[j] = laneOrder[j + 1];
          laneOrder[j + 1] = tempLane;
          
          }
      }
  }
  
  boolean significantDifference = (densities[0] - densities[3]) >= densityThreshold;
  
  // Cycling all the traffic lights
  if (significantDifference = true)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < laneOrder.length; i++) 
    {
      switch (laneOrder[i]) 
      {
        case 0: // North Road
              stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
              stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
                    
          break;
            
        case 1: // South Road
              stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
              stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
                    
          break;
            
        case 2: // West Road
              stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
              stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
                   
          break;
            
        case 3: // East Road
              stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
              stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
                    
          break;
      }
      // Wait time = desities[0] * 3;
    }
  }
  
  // default traffic light phase, no priority 
  else
  {
    //North
    stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
    stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    
    // Wait time = 60
    
    //South
    stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
    stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    
    // Wait time = 60
    
    //West
    stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN);
    stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    // Wait time = 60
    
    //East
    stopLineNorth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineSouth.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineWest.setSignal(SIGNAL_RED);
    stopLineEast.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN;
    // Wait time = 60
    
  }
}

I have tried using State Charts for better control of timing and delays, and while implementing the default cycle with delays is straightforward, I'm having trouble how to loop when sorting the lanes by density and cycle the phasing to the sorted lanes.
My State Chart of the algorithm
Result of the State Chart

Hi, welcome to SOF. Could you boil this down a bit to the root issue you face? Do you want to know how to sort objects by characteristics? What exactly do you struggle with?

There is no way to set custom intervals for the traffic lights. And also, the statechart is always sequential with only one traffic light open.
If I understood your problem correctly, you should create an event that occur periodically and cyclic (for example, every 120 seconds). In this event function, you evaluate the densities and you take action accordingly.
A traffic light block controls all the intersection StopLine, and you must do this control manually. If you remove the traffic light, you are able to control individual stop lines signals using stopLine1.setSignal(SIGNAL_GREEN) for example. https://anylogic.help/markup/stopline.html
Thus, you could evaluate every minute, check the densities and decide  to open/close signals according to your adaptative rule. The TrafficLight block assumes you have some cyclic conditions, which you do not have.
